# Method overload of ConnectReceiveEndpoint changed after upgrading MassTransit

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am upgrading from 5.3.2 to version 5.5.3 and the following code does not compile. I get the errors

> 'IReceiveEndpointConfigurator' does not contain a definition for 'BindMessageExchanges' and no accessible extension method 'BindMessageExchanges' accepting a first argument of type 'IReceiveEndpointConfigurator' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> 'IReceiveEndpointConfigurator' does not contain a definition for 'Bind' and no accessible extension method 'Bind' accepting a first argument of type 'IReceiveEndpointConfigurator' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

It seems that **p** is `IReceiveEndpointConfigurator` and not `IRabbitMqReceiveEndpointConfigurator` anymore. There seems to be changes on the overloaded methods or extension methods.

What overloaded method should I use instead? The code is used in testscenarios to hook up temporary queues/exchanges. `_host` is of type `IRabbitMqHost`

```
_handle = _host.ConnectReceiveEndpoint(p =>
        {
            p.BindMessageExchanges = false;
            p.Handler<T>(context =>
            {
                _receivedMessage = context.Message;
                _messageReceived.Set();
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            });
            p.Bind<T>(z =>
            {
                z.ExchangeType = "direct";
                z.RoutingKey = _routingKey;
            });
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

The method is right there:
https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport/IRabbitMqHost.cs#L47

Are you specifying a queue name?

Comment: No we are currently using the overload without specifying queue name. So what queue name should we provide for temporary queues

Comment: Does mastransit generate a random name if I pass string.empty. should I generate random names on my own.

Comment: You can use the host.Topology to create a temporary queue name, it's in there someplace, not sure exactly where.